# Can an Object hold an Array of it's own object

Tags: java, arrays, list, object

I've have an Object Accounts which has sub Accounts within it.

I both have the same structure I need there to be one parent account with 1 to many children associated with. They are both going to be mapped to the same object class (which I cannot edit, always the way!)  on different objects. So Is it possible to have an array of the Object within the actual object itself. Or should I make a List of the parent and within that list have a list of children?

**EDIT:** I cannot edit the class.

I am currently working like this:

```
Account acc = new Account()
Account[] subacc = new Account[length]
```

Now this is the question. Without editing Account How can I associate Parent and children. I assume the only way is to create a wrapper object to hold both of them? Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried it? It should not be a problem.

Comment: Or rather, what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
class Account
{
    private Account[] children;
}
```

Absolutely. (And the same is true for a `List<Account>`, or just a single `Account` field etc.)

Comment: Just make sure you don't end up with circular references :)

Comment: @Ankur: Circular references *can* be okay... so long as you're aware of them and don't try to (say) recurse down forever.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In fact the array can hold a reference to the object itself.

When you are managing objects, you are dealing with references (aka pointers) and you can do the usual stuff with them. Only when you do myObject.myMethod() they are derreferenced to get the actual object.

```
public class MyTest {
  public myTest[] myArray = new MyTest[10];
  public MyTest() {
    this.myArray[0] = this;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take any one based on your need, take `List` if you need expandable `array` also you will have supports of methods

Following compiles fine :

```
class Foo {

    private Foo[] arr = new Foo[10];
    private List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly

```
public class Account {

    private String id;
    private List<Account> linkedAccounts;

    //Getter and setter

}
```

If you want something like I mentioned above, then yes. Unless you clearly state what you need to achieve, that's what I can show.

The `linkedAccounts` attribute contains a list of `Account` (usually linked to the parent account object).

Answer (score 1):

No reason why you can't have parent/child relationship among objects of the same type. For example, you could walk up the resulting tree until

> account.getParent() == null

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got you but you can do seomething like the below:

```
  public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Person> Chldren { get; set; }
    }


    public class MyClass
    {

        public static void Main()
        {
            Person myDad=new Person();
            myDad.Chldren=new List<Person>()
                              {
                                  {new Person()},
                                  {new Person()}
                              };

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that what a node in an [n-ary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree) contains? Each node can contain up to at most n children. Each node in a binary tree can have 2 children. Each node in a ternary tree can have  a list (or other collection) of up to 3 children. Etc.

Am I misunderstanding the question?